# How to restrict a multiselect dropdown upto certain number of selections

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I need help with Angular 6. I'm using a PrimeNG kind of library (not exactly PrimeNG). Therefore I'm unable to see the source code or create an stacklitz for my question (sorry for that).

Here is the usage:

```
<lib-multiselect [(ngModel)]="categories1" name="category" placeholder="Select any 3 categories">
    <lib-multiselect-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">
        {{ category?.name }}
    </lib-multiselect-option>
</lib-multiselect>
```

**Typescipt:**

```
  categories = [];
  categories1 = [];
  category = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories.push({ name: "Category-1"});
    this.categories.push({ name: "Category-2");
    this.categories.push({ name: "Category-3"});
    this.categories.push({ name: "Category-4"});
    this.categories.push({ name: "Category-5"});
    this.categories1 = this.categories;
  }
```

The component is working fine. But there's no way I can restrict the number of selections to 3 (say). I asked the developers of the library they said they don't have any property to ensure this. So
I tried this:

```
setRadio(e) {
    const exists = this.localArray.includes(e.name);

    if (exists) {
        this.removeElementFromLocalArray(e);
    } else {
        if (!this.localArray.includes(e.name)) {
            if (this.localArray.length >= 2) {
                // console.log('cannot push');
                alert('Limit reached! Maximum 2 selections are allowed');
                return false;
            } else {
                this.localArray.push(e.name);
                // console.log('after adding ', this.localArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My logic is correct. Alert box is popping up at the right time but still selection is happening on UI. Though it is actually not selected but the UI still shows a tick mark. Please help.

Comment: When you select option, then which event gets occur?

Comment: What do you do with `categories1`? If it is a form that is submitted, you could validate the length on submit.